# MySQL Update in While loop

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, while-loop

There is probably a simple solution to this but I can't figure it out:
I'm trying to UPDATE in a While loop (from the phpMyAdmin panel):

```
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE proc_name()
BEGIN
DECLARE c int ;
SET c = 509 ;
WHILE c<637 DO
  UPDATE foobar
    SET `qwerty`= 10000+c-509
    WHERE `product_id` IS c ;
  SET c = c + 1 ;
END WHILE;
END $$
DELIMITER ;
```

The error:

> ..near 'c ; SET c = c + 1 ; END WHILE ; END' at line 9.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try changing it to this:

```
WHERE `product_id` = c ;
```

Comment: @Igor -- it passed -- you mean the SP was created successfully?  And then you called it?  Does your table have a product id of 509?